# Round price up to next 5 or 10 hundredths

Tags: php, decimal, rounding, magento-1.9

I want to round up prices to ensure a `5` or `0` in the hundredths place.

e.g. I have the price `£74.31` I want to round to the closest `74.35` or if above `£74.36` then `£74.40` and the decimals I always want to end with `5` and `0`.

More examples:

```
£74.31 would be round up to £74.35
£74.32 would be round up to £74.35
£74.33 would be round up to £74.35
£74.34 would be round up to £74.35
£74.35 would be round up to £74.35

£74.36 would be round up to £74.40
£74.37 would be round up to £74.40
£74.38 would be round up to £74.40
£74.39 would be round up to £74.40
£74.40 would be round up to £74.40
```

I attempted to round up prices with the below

```
round(($price * $rate) * 2, 1)/2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this makes sense, but if it doesn't some quick background:

The `round($number * 2) / 2` you posted works because there are two halves in any whole. If you wanted to round to quarters you would use `round($number * 4)/4`, and fifths would be `round($number * 5)/5`. etc, etc.

Because it appears as if you want to round to the nearest nickel, there are 20 nickels in a dollar. Problem is that it is willing to move itself up/down. The same thing happens using `ceil()`, but it will only move upwards, which appears to be what you want.

```
function round_to_nickel($item, $decimals=false){
    $num = ceil($item * 20) / 20;
    return ($decimals) ? number_format($num, (int)$decimals) : $num;
}
```

Comment: You are right.  It is a floating point math problem -- a problem only introduced by my loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with this logic,

```
<?php
    $x = 74.31;
    $number = $x*100;
    if($number % 5){
      $number = $number + 5 - ($number % 5);
    }else{
      $number = $number - ($number % 5);
    }
    $number /=100;
    echo number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/748595

Comment: @SakthibalanA not work in these cases:-https://eval.in/748654 And https://eval.in/748662  . need to be 74.50  and 75

Comment: Those demo links appear to be broken.  This answer looks to be correct when I test it.  Please re-prove the alleged fault in this snippet. @Anant

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful if your incoming value is calculated because floating point math can yield unexpected results!  Please see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/2943403)

My demonstration uses a loop to increment the input number by `.01`.  This introduces problems due to precision. See these demonstrations: https://3v4l.org/Ao1oG and https://3v4l.org/RQoGl. If your input is statically declared as a float to exactly 2 decimal places, then don't worry for this task.

As a cheap way to mitigate potential disruptions for this task, after multiplying the input by `20` **subtracting `.1`**, then call `ceil()`, finally divide by `20`.  By effect, numbers originally ending in 5 (in the hundredths place) will not be rounded up, but actually remain unchanged.

For clean, concise formatting of the new float value, I recommend `printf()` with a format parameter that demands two decimal places in the output.

```
printf('£%.02f', $num, ceil($num * 20 - .1) / 20)
```

Unit Tests : ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BbbJf))

```
for ($num = 74.30; $num < 74.41; $num += .01) {
    var_export(sprintf('%.02f => £%.02f', $num, ceil($num * 20 - .1) / 20));
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
'74.30 => £74.30'
'74.31 => £74.35'
'74.32 => £74.35'
'74.33 => £74.35'
'74.34 => £74.35'
'74.35 => £74.35'  #not rounded up to 74.40
'74.36 => £74.40'
'74.37 => £74.40'
'74.38 => £74.40'
'74.39 => £74.40'
'74.40 => £74.40'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use php `floor()` and `ceil()` and `round()` function as per your requirement.

Comment: i know but he have to use substr to remove sign and conver value in float and this function has to apply